# Cannot Commit to the SVN using eclipse and Subversie - CHECKOUT can only be performed on a version resource [at this time]

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

When I try to commit some changes, I get the following error:

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: E200007: Commit failed (details follow):

svn: E200007: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200007: CHECKOUT can only be performed on a version resource [at this time].
svn: E175002: CHECKOUT request failed on '/repos/mysystem/!svn/rvr/123456/trunk/java-src/lang/myfile.properties'
```

Here what I have:

1. Right Click on the project -> Clean and Refresh didn't work.
2. libsvn-java is already installed ,
3. commit from command line worked perfectly. I used command:

   svn ci /path/to/file
4. I have Eclipse EE Neon Release (4.6.0)

   Subversie - SVN Team Provider 4.0.0

   java version "1.8.0_101"

   svn, version 1.8.10 (r1615264)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please let us know the error that you are getting?

Comment: Thanks @techprat for your answer, I edited my question to show the error.

Comment: I already explained in my question that the solution in the duplicate question didn't work out. i.e. Right click -> Team -> Clean / Refresh. So I hope that @bahrep would kindly reopen the question